# How does Twisted reactor loop know that it should invoke recv and how does it know which function to call?

Tags: python, sockets, twisted

I am testing a client server in twisted. There are three identical servers, each is sending a large chunk of data through sendall(). There is a client which implements a reactor and receives data as follows:

```
Task 1: got 60 bytes of poetry from 127.0.0.1:10000
Task 2: got 10 bytes of poetry from 127.0.0.1:10001
Task 3: got 10 bytes of poetry from 127.0.0.1:10002
Task 1: got 30 bytes of poetry from 127.0.0.1:10000
Task 3: got 10 bytes of poetry from 127.0.0.1:10002
Task 2: got 10 bytes of poetry from 127.0.0.1:10001
...
Task 1: 3003 bytes of poetry
Task 2: 623 bytes of poetry
Task 3: 653 bytes of poetry
Got 3 poems in 0:00:10.134220
```

I am puzzled by how the client knows (1) performing `for` loop in `poetry_main()` until all data are received, even though `socket.error` occurs each time after the client receives a small chunk of data from a server (2) using `doRead` function; it is not referenced anywhere except in class function definition. It will be great if someone can explain this!

Client

```
# This is the Twisted Get Poetry Now! client, version 1.0.

# NOTE: This should not be used as the basis for production code.
# It uses low-level Twisted APIs as a learning exercise.

import datetime, errno, optparse, socket

from twisted.internet import main


def parse_args():
    usage = """usage: %prog [options] [hostname]:port ...

This is the Get Poetry Now! client, Twisted version 1.0.
Run it like this:

  python get-poetry.py port1 port2 port3 ...

If you are in the base directory of the twisted-intro package,
you could run it like this:

  python twisted-client-1/get-poetry.py 10001 10002 10003

to grab poetry from servers on ports 10001, 10002, and 10003.

Of course, there need to be servers listening on those ports
for that to work.
"""

    parser = optparse.OptionParser(usage)

    _, addresses = parser.parse_args()

    if not addresses:
        print parser.format_help()
        parser.exit()

    def parse_address(addr):
        if ':' not in addr:
            host = '127.0.0.1'
            port = addr
        else:
            host, port = addr.split(':', 1)

        if not port.isdigit():
            parser.error('Ports must be integers.')

        return host, int(port)

    return map(parse_address, addresses)


class PoetrySocket(object):

    poem = ''

    def __init__(self, task_num, address):
        self.task_num = task_num
        self.address = address
        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.sock.connect(address)
        self.sock.setblocking(0)

        # tell the Twisted reactor to monitor this socket for reading
        from twisted.internet import reactor
        reactor.addReader(self)

    def fileno(self):
        try:
            return self.sock.fileno()
        except socket.error:
            return -1

    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        self.sock.close()

        # stop monitoring this socket
        from twisted.internet import reactor
        reactor.removeReader(self)

        # see if there are any poetry sockets left
        for reader in reactor.getReaders():
            if isinstance(reader, PoetrySocket):
                return

        reactor.stop() # no more poetry

    def doRead(self):
        bytes = ''
        count = 0

        while True:
            count += 1
            try:
                bytesread = self.sock.recv(1024)
                if not bytesread:
                    break
                else:
                    bytes += bytesread
                    print ('bytesread read: ', bytes)
            except socket.error, e:
                if e.args[0] == errno.EWOULDBLOCK:
                    break
                return main.CONNECTION_LOST

            print ('count read: ', count)

        print ('task? : ', bytes)
        if not bytes:
            print 'Task %d finished' % self.task_num
            return main.CONNECTION_DONE
        else:
            msg = 'Task %d: got %d bytes of poetry from %s'
            print  msg % (self.task_num, len(bytes), self.format_addr())

        self.poem += bytes

    def logPrefix(self):
        return 'poetry'

    def format_addr(self):
        host, port = self.address
        return '%s:%s' % (host or '127.0.0.1', port)


def poetry_main():
    addresses = parse_args()

    start = datetime.datetime.now()

    sockets = [PoetrySocket(i + 1, addr) for i, addr in enumerate(addresses)]

    from twisted.internet import reactor
    reactor.run()

    elapsed = datetime.datetime.now() - start

    for i, sock in enumerate(sockets):
        print 'Task %d: %d bytes of poetry' % (i + 1, len(sock.poem))

    print 'Got %d poems in %s' % (len(addresses), elapsed)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    poetry_main()
```

Server

```
# This is the blocking version of the Slow Poetry Server.

import optparse, os, socket, time


def parse_args():
    usage = """usage: %prog [options] poetry-file

This is the Slow Poetry Server, blocking edition.
Run it like this:

  python slowpoetry.py <path-to-poetry-file>

If you are in the base directory of the twisted-intro package,
you could run it like this:

  python blocking-server/slowpoetry.py poetry/ecstasy.txt

to serve up John Donne's Ecstasy, which I know you want to do.
"""

    parser = optparse.OptionParser(usage)

    help = "The port to listen on. Default to a random available port."
    parser.add_option('--port', type='int', help=help)

    help = "The interface to listen on. Default is localhost."
    parser.add_option('--iface', help=help, default='localhost')

    help = "The number of seconds between sending bytes."
    parser.add_option('--delay', type='float', help=help, default=.7)

    help = "The number of bytes to send at a time."
    parser.add_option('--num-bytes', type='int', help=help, default=10)

    options, args = parser.parse_args()

    if len(args) != 1:
        parser.error('Provide exactly one poetry file.')

    poetry_file = args[0]

    if not os.path.exists(args[0]):
        parser.error('No such file: %s' % poetry_file)

    return options, poetry_file


def send_poetry(sock, poetry_file, num_bytes, delay):
    """Send some poetry slowly down the socket."""

    inputf = open(poetry_file)

    while True:
        bytes = inputf.read(num_bytes)

        if not bytes: # no more poetry :(
            sock.close()
            inputf.close()
            return

        print 'Sending %d bytes' % len(bytes)

        try:
            sock.sendall(bytes) # this is a blocking call
        except socket.error:
            sock.close()
            inputf.close()
            return

        time.sleep(delay)


def serve(listen_socket, poetry_file, num_bytes, delay):
    while True:
        sock, addr = listen_socket.accept()

        print 'Somebody at %s wants poetry!' % (addr,)

        send_poetry(sock, poetry_file, num_bytes, delay)


def main():
    options, poetry_file= parse_args()

    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    sock.bind((options.iface, options.port or 0))

    sock.listen(5)

    print 'Serving %s on port %s.' % (poetry_file, sock.getsockname()[1])

    serve(sock, poetry_file, options.num_bytes, options.delay)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Found it [here](http://krondo.com/?p=1445)! The class implements an interface whose functions are part of the event driven loop.